# Navigate back to the last cursor position in Visual Studio for Mac

Tags: c#, visual-studio-mac

I am looking for a shortcut that will lead me to previous cursor position.
To clarify, I am looking specifically for Visual Studio on **Mac**, not Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default shortcut is: <kbd>Option</kbd>-<kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>◄</kbd>. You can set it in Preferences->Environment->KeyBindings->View->Navigate Back

Comment: Control+Command+Left arrow in my case (Visual Studio Community 2019 for Mac)

Answer (score 1):

TLDR:  Control+Command+Left arrow in my case (Community Edition for MAC)